# Deploy Spring Boot application with Elastic BeansTalk CLI

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application on Elastic BeansTalk and it works perfectly. Also deploying the jar has no issues at all.

I'm trying to deploying the app using the EB command line interface but I get this error I can't understand

> darko [Analytics] $ eb deploy
>   Uploading Volta demo/app-44a2-181003_171058.jar to S3. This may take a while.
>   Upload Complete.
>   2018-10-03 15:11:00    INFO    Environment update is starting.
>   2018-10-03 15:11:09    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
>   2018-10-03 15:11:13    ERROR   Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile.
>   2018-10-03 15:11:15    ERROR   [Instance: i-0252754fc608a26ac] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ics/pom.properties
>   Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile.
>   Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile. 
>   Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/01_configure_application.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
>   2018-10-03 15:11:15    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
>   2018-10-03 15:11:15    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0252754fc608a26ac'. Aborting the operation.
>   2018-10-03 15:11:16    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.

Any idea about what's missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to deploy successfully. All I needed was the correct file name inside the config.yml inside .elasticbeanstalk directory. Here is my working config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: analytics-env
environment-defaults:
  analytics-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
deploy:
  artifact: target/analytics-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
global:
  application_name: Analytics
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-central-1::platform/Java 8 running
    on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.5
  default_region: eu-central-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

Comment: Yes, or add a Procfile that contains deploy:
  artifact: my_source_bundle.zip